# Delete elements from dicts in list if value of dict key is in otherlist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code like the following:

```
dicts = [
        {'one': 'hello',
         'two': 'world',
         'three': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
         'four': 'foo'
        },
        {'one': 'pizza',
         'two': 'cake',
         'three': ['f', 'g', 'h', 'e'],
         'four': 'bar'
        }
       ]

letters = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r','t','y']

dedup_rows = [row for row in dicts if row['three'][3] not in letters]
```

The objective is that `dedup_rows` should contain the elements from `dicts` in which the fourth element of the list stored in `three` is not contained in the list `letters`. Essentially, `delete row from dicts if row['three'][3] in letters`. The output from the above code would be:

```
dedup_rows: [
             {'one': 'hello',
              'two': 'world',
              'three': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
              'four': 'foo'
             }
            ]
```

The code I have is working but in practice both `dicts` and `letters` contain hundreds of thousands of elements each and so execution is slow as each iteration over `dicts` also requires a full iteration over `letters`.

Is there a more optimal way of doing this in Python?

Comment: make letters a set `letters = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r','t','y'}`

Comment: A set lookup is usually faster comparing to its list counterpart.

Comment: sorting `letters` will decrease the average time but it won't change the degree of complexity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code `dedup_rows = [row for row in dicts if row['three'][3] not in letters]` is of square complexity. since it is iterating over `dicts` and on `letters` for each element of `dicts`. 
If both of your lists contain a large number of elements. You should consider data structure with lookup time complexity of the order of one. For your case [Python Sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) are perfect. You can read more about it.
All you need to do is convert `letters = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r','t','y']` to a set with syntax `set(letters)` and find with syntax `x in letters_set`.

```
dicts = [
    {'one': 'hello',
     'two': 'world',
     'three': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
     'four': 'foo'
    },
    {'one': 'pizza',
     'two': 'cake',
     'three': ['f', 'g', 'h', 'e'],
     'four': 'bar'
    }
   ]

letters = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r','t','y']
letters_set = set(letters)

dedup_rows = [row for row in dicts if row['three'][3] not in letters_set]
```

> like this you can change the algorithm from order of n square to order of n.

Comment: Thanks, this works very nicely and was able to cut the execution time of my function significantly. I'll try to learn more about Python sets and use them more often in future when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really dealing with hundreds of thousands of records with rows with hundreds of thousands of values each, then perhaps a pure in memory python approach is not the best way forward.

There are a few things you can do that will improve performance:

- Stream in records from your source (file? database?) instead of loading them at once
- Use a generator which reads the records one at a time and then yields them if they do or don't match (never keep them in a list)
- Use sets for set comparisons which will be a lot faster for many values

In general though, this begs the question of where you are getting these records from?

If they are stored in any kind of database, then performing a query at source which rules out the rows you don't want, and provides a cursor to iterate through the rows you do want in a memory efficient way sounds like a better way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I'm retrieving the records from an API so at least initially they have to be loaded in memory. For my use case I believe a set is the right way to go but this answers contains a lot of useful info.

Comment: Does the API return 100k records at a time, or are you collecting them together first before you process them?